# how to get a cordova plugin for construct2

Tags: cordova, construct-2

I've been working on a platformer game in construct2 for a school project and I needed to use a cordova plugin for construct2, after searching for a while I've found free plugin created by cranberrygame but there is a tricky way to get it for free.I also found that c2r185 is released with the plugin but I already had r178 and can't afford another release license.
so, anyone could help me get these plugins for free and without tricky ways.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest construct software. You can then install cordova on your computer and directly create it from there without getting a license.